# Bottle py and Jinja2 global variable

Tags: python, jinja2, bottle

I am using bottle.py framework along with Jinja2 templates in a new application.

Whenever a user logs into the application I would like to add a new global Jinja2 variable with the name of the active user, so in a partial template (the header) I can display this name.

In my python (bottle) file I've tried several things according to what I googled so far, but no success yet.

This is the last thing I tried inside a function:

```
import jinja2
env = jinja2.Environment(loader=jinja2.FileSystemLoader('templates'))
env.globals['myglobal'] = 'My global'
#env.globals.update({'myglobal': 'My global'})
```

But, when putting this into the header template: {{myglobal}} it simply doesn't show up.

Since this is my first time with bottle and jinja2 anyone knows how can achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case you need to use before_request hook, just like below:

```
from bottle import Jinja2Template

@hook('before_request')
def before_request():
    Jinja2Template.defaults['myglobal'] = 'My global'
```

Comment: Not sure you want to execute that on every `request`. Solution proposed by @DanGayle looks better to me.

Answer (score 4):

I have a similar setup, and this works for me using the BaseTemplate built into bottle:

```py
from bottle import BaseTemplate
BaseTemplate.defaults['myglobal'] = 'My global'
```

Comment: My answer was a solution to the actual question, using the variables the op used in their question. Please don't re-write it into something entirely different, although that answer might be correct it is not *my* answer.

Comment: Well, I don't see anywhere in the question `BaseTemplate` and the question is Jinja2 specific. I only edited your answer to try and help others. If it's your will to keep it like that, then it's fine to me.

Answer (score 1):

```
from bottle import Jinja2Template
Jinja2Template.defaults['foo'] = 'bar'
```

This is to add a variable to every rendered jinja2 templates. If you want to add a filter, here is what I did:

```
import functools
from bottle import jinja2_view

def foo():
    return 'bar'
view = functools.partial(jinja2_view, template_settings={
    'filters': {'foo': foo}})
```

You can set any jinja2 settings using this.